# wordpress form post error 404

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, form-submit

I am keep getting 404 Error whenever I press submit in the following input form. I have tried changing "name" so that it would likely to be unique and yet I am still getting 404 Error. Can anybody help?

```
<form action="template.php" method="post">
Ticker: <input type="text" name="myName" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myName']) ? $_POST['myName'] : '' ?>"/><br><br>

Financial Statement Item:
<select name="myFin_item">
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
<option value="all">All</option>

</select><br>


<input type="Submit" /></form>
```

Comment: based on what is provided, the only thing I can think of is that your `<form action=""` file is not available if you are getting a 404 on submit.

Comment: Yes, looks like that was the problem. Thank you!